# Errors: object not found when trying to define object

Tags: r

I am trying to create an object using `<-` and I keep getting an error.

If I paste this exact same line into a new R script, it works fine, no errors. I have the new object with the right result from the `left_join`. What is this?

```
Complete_df <- left_join(AGB, anpp, by= c("Lat", "Lon", "Year"), all = TRUE)
```

> Error in
>   -----------------------------------------------------------Complete_df <- left_join(AGB, :object 'Complete_df' not found

Another example, same error when trying to define an object:

```
brienen <- read.csv("C:/Users/tatia/Dropbox/Exercise/Data/data.csv"
```

> Error in
>   -----------------------------------------------------------brienen <- read.csv("C:/Users/tatia/Dropbox/Exercise/Data/data.csv") :    object
>   'brienen' not found

Comment: Your assignment operator may be overloaded with the function of another operator (i.e. instead of assignment it does, say, addition)... Check in your console if ` `<-` `  returns `.Primitive("<-")`.

Comment: @Luminita if I enter only `<-` in my console, it returns the following message > Error: unexpected assignment in "<-"

Comment: You need to add the backticks.